# Application interrupts like crazy

Tags: android, c++, exception, interrupt, sigint

I had a perfectly running C++ (Android native) application .. then I introduced some **try { } catch {}** statements and if I debug the application it interrupts like crazy in random, correct pieces of code.
If I run the application it stops for an interrupt Zygote (**app_process**) complains about signal **2**, which is **SIGINT**.

I had a few try-catch clauses in my application that was running fine before I added a ton of try-catch clauses. At this point I am sure that there are a lot of nested try-catch blocks, maybe the Android OS can't handle that many interrupts for nested blocks ?

I would like to mention that on Windows the same code runs flawlessly.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a full rebuild. Your debug info may be off. That's the best answer one can give with the info in the OP.

Comment: I rebuilt it a few times from scratch, even tryied with or without (-fexceptions)